# Need help with Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

I have to write a validation rule on the standard object **'TASK'** . If the picklist value of the **'Subject'** field is **'Status Update'** then the **'Description'** field should not have any value. I am trying to write the rule but always I am getting the below error.

**Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected Picklist, received Text**

Below is my Validation Rule.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL( Subject , "Status Update") ,  NOT( Description = NULL ) )
```

Please help me in knowing where I am going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: I checked with status picklist and this formula is working with that but not working with subject

Comment: Is subject a text or a picklist? I think that subject is normally a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
AND(Subject="Status Update",NOT(Description=NULL))
```

It is working fine

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Your Subject field might be of Text data type, while `ISPICKVAL()` works on picklist data types.  To check text field, you can use `TEXT()` method. The below validation rule should work fine -

```
AND(TEXT(Subject) = "Status Update", NOT(Description=NULL))
```